# How to add images files while converting .py to .exe?

Tags: python, tkinter, exe, pyinstaller

I have created a Tkinter-based app, which uses images as icons for buttons.

And now I converted it to .exe using `auto-py-to-exe` (PyInstaller).

But the output file doesn't run because it can't find the required images. How can I merge the images files with the .exe file?

Here is the app code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *


root = tk.Tk()
img = PhotoImage(file=r'E:\project\videos\icon\rec.png')
root.tk.call('wm', 'iconphoto', root._w, img)
root.title('Cam Recorder')
cam_icon = PhotoImage(file=r'E:\project\videos\icon\webcam0.png')
com_icon = PhotoImage(file=r'E:\project\videos\icon\webcam1.png')


def change_w():
    if webcam_btn.image == cam_icon:
        webcam_btn.config(image=com_icon)
        webcam_btn.image = com_icon
    else:
        webcam_btn.config(image=cam_icon)
        webcam_btn.image = cam_icon


frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()

webcam_btn = tk.Button(
    frame,
    image=cam_icon,
    width=70,
    height=80,
    relief=FLAT,
    command=change_w,
    )
webcam_btn.grid(row=0, column=2)
webcam_btn.image = cam_icon
root.mainloop()
```

And here is the screenshot of the auto-py-to-exe:

[image: eg]

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use temporary files, with their binary embeded in your code as `byte`, like this:
1) Use `print(open('path-to-img', 'rb').read())` to get binary.

2) Add

```
with open('your_temp_path.png', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(b'your_binary_data')
```

3) Use `os.remove('your_temp_path.png')` at the end of your code to remove the temp file.

Hope that's helpful!

Comment: It's a bad idea to create temporary files in most of cases, especially in the app's working directory instead of the special system directory that is designed for it (take a look at the [tempfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html) module). If it comes to, you may create a file-like object right in the memory, without creating any files because Python provides [BytesIO file-like object from io module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO). And, of course, don't forget that, in this particular case, you can just include additional files.

Comment: :) sorry, not the place to talk about that